# Push is not a function - Angular

Tags: angular

I am making an app with angular and i am getting this error, push is not a function in browser.I don't understand why it is giving me this error. Have already searched online but so far no luck Can anyone help?
Plus it only happens in else part. Like when there is already a product in local storage

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebService } from './web.service';
import Product from './models/product';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ProductsService {
      cartProduct:Product[]
      constructor(private  webService: WebService) { }
      getAllProducts(){
        return this.webService.get('FoodItems');
      }
      getBreadProduct(){
        return this.webService.get('FoodItems/Bread');
      }
      getDairyProduct(){
        return this.webService.get('FoodItems/Dairy');
      }
      getFruitsProduct(){
        return this.webService.get('FoodItems/Fruits');
      }
      getOrganicProduct(){
        return this.webService.get('FoodItems/Organic');
      }
      getVegetablesProducts(){
        return this.webService.get('FoodItems/Vegetables');
      }
      getSeasoningAndSpicesProducts(){
        return this.webService.get('FoodItems/Seasoning-and-spices');
      }
      AddProductInCart(cartP:Product)
      {

        this.cartProduct=this.GetProductInCart()
        if(this.cartProduct==null)
        {
          this.cartProduct=[]
          this.cartProduct.push(cartP)
          localStorage.setItem('cartProduct',JSON.stringify(cartP))

        }
        else{
        this.cartProduct.push(cartP)
        localStorage.setItem('cartProduct',JSON.stringify("cartP"))
      }}
      GetProductInCart()
      {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartProduct'))
      }

    }
```

Comment: Your problem is `null` !== `undefined`.

Comment: Can you please explain

Comment: Your comparison `this.cartProduct==null` is failing because the value of an unassigned field is `undefined` rather than `null` .

Answer (score 0):

replace this line:

```
if(this.cartProduct==null)
```

with this:

```
if(this.cartProduct === null || this.cartProduct === undefined)
```

or replace this line:

```
this.cartProduct=this.GetProductInCart()
```

with this line:

```
this.cartProduct=this.GetProductInCart() || [];
```

Comment: I am having issue with else part.